# How to remove a UI element from a web page that's not present at document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a regular user of a site https://www.lingq.com. The site recently added a "share" side panel, that slides in from the left a few seconds after a page is loaded. It's annoying, it covers up a portion of the text on the site. After a while I got really fed up with having to manually click it away every time. I'm using GreaseMonkey to remove it, but the problem is the element is not yet there when document.ready occurs.

I'm getting around this by using timeouts.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ()
{
  setTimeout(function () {
    jQuery('#at4-share').remove()
  }, 5000)
  setTimeout(function () {
    jQuery('#at4-share').remove()
  }, 10000)
});
```

After some experimenting I've settled on two timers. The first one (after 5 seconds) usually removes the thing almost the moment it shows up. The second one is there because sometimes the sidebar will not have appeared in time. The site does quite a bit of javascript processing upon loading, and the thing appears only after it's done.

While my solution works, it's crude and ugly. I'd like a solution that reliably removes the panel, no matter how long it takes for it to appear. Ideally, I shouldn't even see the panel on the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see a side panel, is it visible only when you are registered? Are there any events triggered when the sidebar is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

They are currently implemented in Firefox as `MutationObserver` and in Chrome as the vendor-prefixed `WebKitMutationObserver`:

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    // fired when a mutation occurs
    console.log(mutations, observer);
    // ...
});

// define what element should be observed by the observer
// and what types of mutations trigger the callback
observer.observe(document, {
  subtree: true,
  attributes: true
  //...
});
```

This example listens for DOM changes on `document` and its entire subtree, and it will fire on changes to element attributes as well as structural changes. The draft spec has a full list of valid mutation listener properties:

> **childList**
>
> Set to true if mutations to target's children are to be observed.
>
> **attributes**
>
> Set to true if mutations to target's attributes are to be observed.
>
> **characterData**
>
> Set to true if mutations to target's data are to be observed.
>
> **subtree**
>
> Set to true if mutations to not just target, but also target's
>   descendants are to be observed.
>
> **attributeOldValue**
>
> Set to true if attributes is set to true and target's attribute value
>   before the mutation needs to be recorded.
>
> **characterDataOldValue**
>
> Set to true if characterData is set to true and target's data before
>   the mutation needs to be recorded.
>
> **attributeFilter**
>
> Set to a list of attribute local names (without namespace) if not all
>   attribute mutations need to be observed.

**This should work for you:**

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    jQuery('#at4-share').remove();
});

observer.observe(document, {
  subtree: true
});
```

Comment: You have to set the `observer` to actually observe something: e.g. `attributes`, `childList`

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like a solution that reliably removes the panel, no matter how
>   long it takes for it to appear. Ideally, I shouldn't even see the
>   panel on the page.

Why not simply hide it using css? No matter how long it takes to load the page, by default it would be hidden. Note it won't remove it.

```
#at4-share{
  display:none;
}
```

> I have tried this: GM_addStyle('#at4-share{display:none;!important}')
>   Doesn't do anything

There is a correction, `!important` is placed before `;`:

```
GM_addStyle('#at4-share{display:none !important;}')
```

Comment: This could work, but how do I use it? Can I use GreaseMonkey to set ccs styles? (noob alert)

Comment: I have tried this: 
GM_addStyle('#at4-share{display:none;!important}')
Doesn't do anything.